# PHP - redirect user from page meant for asynchronous JavaScript requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asynchronous

I have a PHP file called `load.php` I load content from asynchronously with JavaScript on my website `example.com`.

I want to redirect the user off the page if they try to go to `example.com/load.php` directly, but still return data if it's being requested through my JavaScript. How do I do this?

```
<?php 

//load.php

// Redirect user if they try to access example.com/load.php directly. Only accept asynchronously calls.

echo "example";

?>

<script>

var load = {
  url: 'https://example.com/load.php?q=example',
  type: "GET",
  success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
  }
};
$.ajax( load );

</static>
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't reliably do that. If you want to try, check for request headers like `X-Requested-With` as outlined in some of the answers to the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!

Comment: Use a `POST` request instead. Without CORS access, no one will be able to `POST` to your page anyways, then.

Comment: Oh that's super smart. Thanks Stack Slave